# How to prevent processes launched by a tmux window from being killed when the window is closed?

Tags: vim, tmux

In tmux, if I create a new window with `tmux new-window vim`, then in `vim` I launch a process (e.g. `:!scite &`), then I exit `vim` (e.g. with `:q`), which will also close the tmux window, the launched process (`scite`) is also killed. How can I prevent this?

Note that the process is not killed if I use `tmux new-window` to create a new shell window first, then manually launch `vim`, then do the rest, and exit the shell.

Comment: why do you need start a backend process from vim. particularly for your example `scite`? do you mean the editor scite?

Comment: Yes, `scite` is a text editor. I use `:!scite %&` from `vim` to edit some file, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch through `setsid` instead (e.g. `:!setsid scite &`).

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is tmux's `remain-on-exit` option.

from `new-window` command :

> When the shell command completes, the window closes.  See the
>   remain-on-exit option to change this behaviour.

the `set-remain-on-exit` doc:

```
   set-remain-on-exit [on | off]
                     Set the remain-on-exit window option for any windows first created in this session.  When this option is true, windows in which the running pro‐
                     gram has exited do not close, instead remaining open but inactivate.  Use the respawn-window command to reactivate such a window, or the
                     kill-window command to destroy it.
```

Comment: True. But I don't want dead windows around. Is there another solution?

Comment: To make sure, I just try the method (`tmux set set-remain-on-exit on`), but found that it does not work, the launched process is still killed.